# What are the standard dimensions for biscuit joints?

Tags: joinery

I recently acquired a Ryobi biscuit jointer and purchased some Freud biscuits. They didn't fit the slots made by the biscuit jointer very well. I am aware that the biscuits are made to swell when wet, so I tried to check the fit  by soaking them in water. They fit better, but it was still not what I would call a snug fit.

So I'm trying to figure out if the biscuit jointer blade is too big, or the biscuits are too thin. Or is there no standard for biscuit thickness?

Comment: Oh the biscuits are too small, not too big! Dang I was about to pass on a tip to shrink them. You can't use them wet, they must be dry (bone dry if at all possible) so soaking in water is absolutely a no-go. Bottom line you need to buy different biscuits, unless a different blade is available that will fit the Ryobi which has a narrower kerf.

Comment: I have been using a Freud biscuit joiner for probably 20 years. I don't like the fence which slips so bought the Ryobi, but the biscuit slots are too wide to properly take the Ryobi biscuits. I'm going to replace the blade with one from Freud. Otherwise my projects are not going to line up adequately. Other than that, I love the operation of the Ryobi presuming the blade switch fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have just purchased one of them myself.

I've jointed a few projects now and they worked brilliantly.  The biscuits I brought were just "off the shelf" size 20.

I think you need different biscuits.  I know it may sound lame but stick a cut into a small piece of wood and take that in for sizing.  I know, I said it was lame but it would help.

Answer (score 0):

4mm or 5/32" kerf is standard.

Comment: Are different sized biscuits all the same thickness? I know FF sized biscuits ("Face Frame") require a different blade. Are they different than 0, 10, and 20 biscuits?